# Getting stale reference exception for below code. I am using for loop. :-(

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written code for comparing dates and performed cancel action for objects depending on time. I want to cancel all objects displayed on UI. But I am not able to cancel all as I am getting stale reference exception. Please help.

```
List<WebElement> EachbookedAppointment = driver.findElements(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("eachbookedappointment")));

System.out.println(EachbookedAppointment.size());

for(int i=0; i< EachbookedAppointment.size();i++)
{
    WebElement AppointmentStatus =EachbookedAppointment.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("AppointmentStatus")));
    System.out.println(AppointmentStatus.getText());
    if(AppointmentStatus.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Scheduled"))
    {
        String bookingTime = EachbookedAppointment.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class ='col-sm-10 time-col appPadding']/span")).getText();
        String year = "2016 ";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(bookingTime);
        sb.append(year).append(bookingTime);
        String UIDate = sb.toString() ;
        System.out.println(UIDate);
        Date date2 = sdfAmerica.parse(UIDate);

        //String appointmentTime = 
        //sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        Date onedaybackdate = DateUtils.addHours(date, -24);

        System.out.println(date2 + "It is UI date");
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");

        if(date2.before(Currentdate) && date2.after(onedaybackdate)){
            System.out.println(Currentdate + "comes after " + onedaybackdate);
            //EachbookedAppointment.get(i);//.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("CancelAppointment")));
            WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("CancelAppointment"))));
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("CancelAppointment"))).click();
            element.click();
            waitUntilSpinnerIsDisplayed();
            Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("AlertMessage"))).getText(), Constant.Cancelwithin24hourMessage);
        }
        else if(date2.after(Currentdate) || date2.before(onedaybackdate))
        {
            System.out.println(date2 + " UI displayed date ");
            EachbookedAppointment.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("CancelAppointment"))).click();
            //WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("CancelAppointment"))));
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("CancelAppointment"))).click();
            WebElement CancelYes = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("CancelYes"))));
            CancelYes.click();
            waitUntilSpinnerIsDisplayed();

            WebElement Alert = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("AlertMessage"))));
            System.out.println(Alert.getText());
            //Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("AlertMessage"))).getText(), Constant.CancelAlertMessage);
            waitUntilSpinnerIsDisplayed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this object changes or gets removed from the list after you click cancel?

Comment: post the error trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you identify any element in selenium and modify it later on, You get this error.

Here in your case the List contains all the elements (EachbookedAppointment) and later on as you mentioned that you are selecting cancel, I assume that this item gets modified OR removed. This breaks the integrity of the list we found earlier and hence you're getting this exception.

**Tips:**

1. After getting the size of the List, store the size in a separate variable and use it for controlling the *for* loop.
2. Don't use this list inside the loop at all, all we wanted is the size of the loop.
3. Inside the loop first statement would be to identify List of all objects (EachbookedAppointment) again and now use this list instead elsewhere in the loop.
4. Referring to your code I can infer that you are trying to Cancel the first active element each time and so, change all `get(i)` with `get(0)`. Thus, you will be operating over the first element of the list each time, which in turn will change each time since we are canceling it inside the loop.

Try to form your own code based on this else if it doesn't work, share the behavior of your application on canceling an object (whether it changes or it gets removed or any other property changes). After I get these details, I'll be able to help you further with the code.

Only thing you need to remember is that if your WebElement gets modified, you'll get this error.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working